# install4j Installer hangs on OS X after preparing assistant

Tags: macos, install4j

Using install4j 5.1.12 to deploy an application to Windows, Linux and OS X. It works on Windows and Linux, but on OS X 10.9 the installer hangs after having prepared the install4j assistant.
I am using the bundled Oracle JRE 1.7.0_60 which can be downloaded inside install4j.

How can I resolve this issue?

I should add that I tried several things to get more information:

1. The debug installer works and installs!
2. Disabling code-signing did not help
3. Using different JREs (we need to use Oracle, 1.7.0_55, 1.8.0_5) did not help
4. Disabling shrinking the runtime did not help
5. Disabling options for trying to obtain root privileges did not help
6. Using different packaging options did not help
7. Using a non-bundled, pre-installed Oracle JRE did not work

This is what jstack says about the hanging installer process:

```
localhost:~ user$ jstack 1540
2014-07-07 12:00:31
Full thread dump Java HotSpot(TM) 64-Bit Server VM (24.60-b09 mixed mode):

"Attach Listener" daemon prio=5 tid=0x00007fd819d10000 nid=0x6c37 waiting on condition [0x0000000000000000]
   java.lang.Thread.State: RUNNABLE

"AWT-AppKit" daemon prio=5 tid=0x00007fd819bb9800 nid=0x303 runnable [0x0000000000000000]
   java.lang.Thread.State: RUNNABLE

"Service Thread" daemon prio=5 tid=0x00007fd8198a8800 nid=0x4503 runnable [0x0000000000000000]
   java.lang.Thread.State: RUNNABLE

"C2 CompilerThread1" daemon prio=5 tid=0x00007fd8198a8000 nid=0x4303 waiting on condition [0x0000000000000000]
   java.lang.Thread.State: RUNNABLE

"C2 CompilerThread0" daemon prio=5 tid=0x00007fd81989f000 nid=0x4103 waiting on condition [0x0000000000000000]
   java.lang.Thread.State: RUNNABLE

"Signal Dispatcher" daemon prio=5 tid=0x00007fd819899800 nid=0x3f03 runnable [0x0000000000000000]
   java.lang.Thread.State: RUNNABLE

"Finalizer" daemon prio=5 tid=0x00007fd819865000 nid=0x2b03 in Object.wait() [0x00000001081b6000]
   java.lang.Thread.State: WAITING (on object monitor)
    at java.lang.Object.wait(Native Method)
    - waiting on <0x00000007dae05630> (a java.lang.ref.ReferenceQueue$Lock)
    at java.lang.ref.ReferenceQueue.remove(ReferenceQueue.java:135)
    - locked <0x00000007dae05630> (a java.lang.ref.ReferenceQueue$Lock)
    at java.lang.ref.ReferenceQueue.remove(ReferenceQueue.java:151)
    at java.lang.ref.Finalizer$FinalizerThread.run(Finalizer.java:209)

"Reference Handler" daemon prio=5 tid=0x00007fd81985f000 nid=0x2903 in Object.wait() [0x00000001080b3000]
   java.lang.Thread.State: WAITING (on object monitor)
    at java.lang.Object.wait(Native Method)
    - waiting on <0x00000007dae051b8> (a java.lang.ref.Reference$Lock)
    at java.lang.Object.wait(Object.java:503)
    at java.lang.ref.Reference$ReferenceHandler.run(Reference.java:133)
    - locked <0x00000007dae051b8> (a java.lang.ref.Reference$Lock)

"main" prio=5 tid=0x00007fd819811000 nid=0x1b03 runnable [0x00000001048fd000]
   java.lang.Thread.State: RUNNABLE
    at java.lang.ClassLoader$NativeLibrary.load(Native Method)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadLibrary1(ClassLoader.java:1965)
    - locked <0x00000007dae04ec0> (a java.util.Vector)
    - locked <0x00000007dae04f18> (a java.util.Vector)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadLibrary0(ClassLoader.java:1890)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadLibrary(ClassLoader.java:1851)
    at java.lang.Runtime.load0(Runtime.java:795)
    - locked <0x00000007dae175d0> (a java.lang.Runtime)
    at java.lang.System.load(System.java:1062)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader$NativeLibrary.load(Native Method)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadLibrary1(ClassLoader.java:1965)
    - locked <0x00000007dae04ec0> (a java.util.Vector)
    - locked <0x00000007dae04f18> (a java.util.Vector)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadLibrary0(ClassLoader.java:1890)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadLibrary(ClassLoader.java:1872)
    at java.lang.Runtime.loadLibrary0(Runtime.java:849)
    - locked <0x00000007dae175d0> (a java.lang.Runtime)
    at java.lang.System.loadLibrary(System.java:1088)
    at sun.security.action.LoadLibraryAction.run(LoadLibraryAction.java:67)
    at sun.security.action.LoadLibraryAction.run(LoadLibraryAction.java:47)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at java.awt.Toolkit.loadLibraries(Toolkit.java:1653)
    at java.awt.Toolkit.<clinit>(Toolkit.java:1682)
    at java.awt.EventQueue.invokeAndWait(EventQueue.java:1251)
    at javax.swing.SwingUtilities.invokeAndWait(SwingUtilities.java:1347)
    at com.install4j.runtime.installer.Installer.getScreenExecutor(Unknown Source)
    at com.install4j.runtime.installer.Installer.runInProcess(Unknown Source)
    at com.install4j.runtime.installer.Installer.main(Unknown Source)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:57)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:606)
    at com.exe4j.runtime.LauncherEngine.launch(Unknown Source)
    at com.install4j.runtime.launcher.MacLauncher.main(Unknown Source)

"VM Thread" prio=5 tid=0x00007fd81985c000 nid=0x2703 runnable 

"VM Periodic Task Thread" prio=5 tid=0x00007fd81989a800 nid=0x4703 waiting on condition 

JNI global references: 239
```

Comment: It hangs while loading the AWT libraries. Have you tried without the bundled JRE?

Comment: @IngoKegel: same deadlock without bundled JRE (updated list, I think I made this comment before, but it got lost without notification, someone messed up there)

Comment: Can I download the installer somewhere? If it's not public, please write to support@ej-technologies.com.

Comment: @IngoKegel: you can get the installer with JRE from http://illarion.org/media/java/install/Illarion-1.0.0.17.dmg

Comment: Weird, it hangs for me with the same stack trace. Can you send your .install4j project file to support@ej-technologies.com?

Comment: @IngoKegel: Sent the .install4j file.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The custom OS X icons file set in the installer options was corrupted. Replacing the file with a fixed version solved this problem.